# Using lists in Tower of Hanoi

Tags: ocaml

I'am new to Ocaml, and I try to programming the tower of hanoi.

My code seem to work until now, I print the move of disk between the rods.

Here is my code:

```
let hanoi n = let rec hanoi_rec n s e i = if n > 0 then
                                          (
                                           hanoi_rec (n - 1) s i e;
                                           let str = "Move disc from " ^ string_of_int s ^ " to " ^ string_of_int e ^ "\n" in
                                           print_string(str);
                                           hanoi_rec (n - 1) i e s
                                           )
    in hanoi_rec n 1 2 3

where n = numbers of disks
s = beginning
e = end
i = internediate
```

and I call it with:

```
let main () = hanoi 2 
let _ = main ();;
```

and print to screen.

*Move disc from 1 to 3*
*Move disc from 1 to 2*
*Move disc from 3 to 2*

Now I want to create a list of movement, not just print it. For example, "`[1;3;1;2;3;2]`". How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is imperative; i.e., it carries out a series of actions in sequence to create its output.

If you want to maintain this imperative character you can use OCaml's impure features. Create a mutable global list (an `int list ref`). Instead of printing the result, add the new value to the beginning of the list. Then at the end, reverse the list.

On the other hand, one of the major reasons to study OCaml is to learn to program functionally. You can solve the problem without using global or mutable values. I suspect the general approach would be to have `hanoi_rec` return a list of moves. This is what I would recommend, as I believe that thinking functionally should be in every programmer's toolkit.

Comment: I try to do it functionally, like you said, but doesn't work, I don't see the approach. I tried to return a list without success.

Comment: I tried with (hanoi_rec (n - 1) s i e)::[s;e]::(hanoi_rec (n - 1) i e s), but return this error : _Error: This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'a The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list_ what does that mean ?

Comment: I find a solution with the concatenation (hanoi_rec (n - 1) s i e)@[s;e]@(hanoi_rec (n - 1) i e s)